# How to animate when page is scrolled to top on jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the size of logo and background of header when scrolltop is equal to zero. The first condition is working but when it backs to top it doesn't work. How to fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowheight = $('html ,body').scrollTop();
        console.log(windowheight);
        if (windowheight > 40){
            $('#headers').css('background-color', 'red'); 
            $('#logoimages').animate({
                'width': '100px'
            }, 500);
            $('#sociallinks').fadeOut();  
        }
        else {
            $('#sociallinks').fadeIn();
            $('#headers').stop().animate({'background-color': "rgba(34,193,195, 0.5)"}, 500);
            $('#logoimages').stop().animate({'width': '100px'},500);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code, and I think it's a lot easier to use CSS "transition" than jQuery "animate" when it needs to do some simpler things!

I tested it and it worked for me this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //adds CSS transition to elements that need animation
    $('#headers,#logoimages').css({"transition": "all 0.5s ease"}); 
    
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowheight = $('html').scrollTop();
        //console.log(windowheight);
        if (windowheight > 40){
            $('#headers').css({'background-color':'red'}); 
            $('#logoimages').css({'width':'100px'});
            $('#sociallinks').fadeOut();  
        }
        else {
            $('#sociallinks').fadeIn();
            $('#headers').css({'background-color':"rgba(34,193,195,0.5)"});
            $('#logoimages').css({'width':'200px'});
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/*only for this test*/

#logoimages{
 background:red;
 width:200px;
}
#headers{
 background:rgba(34,193,195, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!-- only for this test -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headers">headers</div>
<div id="logoimages">logoimages</div>

<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
```

I changed the jQuery "animation" to "transition: all 0.5s ease".

And if you add that to your CSS, you do not even need to add it in the javascript above and it all comes with a better syntax:

```
#logoimages,#headers{
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Hope this helps!